# what's the difference between "dynamic web project" with JSF facet and "JSF project"?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss-tools

When I install "web tools platform" plugins in Eclipse I have a new type of project I can create, called "dynamic web project". In such project I can add JSF facet and then use it to make JSF application.
But when I install "jboss tools" plugins I have a project type called just "JSF project".
What's the difference between both types of projects? Why have jboss tools people created their own type of JSF project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse plugins are created to achieve **some commonly used/desired configurations at much ease.** As you said, you can create a `Dynamic Web Prject` and then perform couple of steps to convert/support JSF. JSF project is created with those required configuration already done for you.

Same example you can apply even between, a `simple project`(created though New -> General->Project option) and `Dynamic Web Project` i.e. you may create a simple project, create files/folders, update the class path etc manually and achieve the same which is directly available through `Dynamic Web Project` option. **These plug-ins/options help you avoid several manual steps to reach a commonly desired functionality.** JSF project is no exception.